# PowerShell - extract contents of a specific folder recursively

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to extract contents of a folder out of a zip file to a different location using powershell.

- zip file: archive.zip
- path in zip: mypath (folder contains multiple files and subfolders)
- destination: c:\destination

If I extract normally I get the folder created:

- Command:Expand-Archive -Path archive.zip -DestinationPath c:\destination
- Folder Created:      c:\destination\mypath

I want to extract the contents of the folder into c:\destination directly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a specific requirement with the values mentioned in the OP then this should do the work

```
$Path='c:\temp\destination';Expand-Archive archive.zip $Path;Move-Item $Path\mypath\* $Path;rm $Path\mypath;
```